# How to add a condition to relation query in FuelPHP?

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I am trying to filter a orm query in fuelphp. Is it possible to check a property on the related model? I want to grab the related "comments" but only if their visibility property is "0". Is it possible to do this in the same query?

This is my current query which grabs the related comments:

```
$top_rated = \Services\Model_Org::query()
                                    ->related('org')
                                    ->related('profile_image')
                                    ->related('comments')
                                    ->where('rating','!=', 'null')
                                    ->order_by('rating','desc')
                                    ->get();
```

This is my attempt which definitely doesn't work because 'visibility' is only a property of the comments not the orgs.

```
$top_rated = \Services\Model_Org::query()
                                    ->related('org')
                                    ->related('profile_image')
                                    ->related('comments')
                                        ->where('visibility', '=', '0')
                                    ->where('rating','!=', 'null')
                                    ->order_by('rating','desc')
                                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what worked if anyone else comes across this question.

```
$top_rated = \Services\Model_Org::query()
                                    ->related('org')
                                    ->related('profile_image')
                                    ->related( array(
                                      'comments' => array(
                                       'where' => array(
                                        array('visible' , '=' , '0')
                                       )
                                      )
                                     )
                                    )
                                    ->where('rating','!=', 'null')
                                    ->order_by('rating','desc')
                                    ->get();
```

Comment: You only gave it 11 hours ;) There are a few of us who do answer fuelphp questions